# How to rescale a list for its elements to be closer to their mean?

Tags: normal-distribution

Given a uniform list of numbers between 0 and 1, I would like to create a bell-shaped normal distribution.

So far, I:

- calculate the z-score for each element in the list (element - mean) / standard deviation
- I clamp the z-scores in the range [-2, 2]  with MAX(-2, MIN(z, 2))
- I rescale each value to [0, 10]  with  ROUND((clampled_z/5+0.5)*10, 1)

The resulting shape is not convincing
[image]

I would like my bell shape to be fatter in the middle with few extrema values. I suppose I need to add some logarithm or exponential transformation to the dataset.

What would be a good way to rescale values proportionally closer to their mean value?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions

Comment: So, do you want to make a normal distribution out of a data that are uniformly distributed? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you need, but this may be helpful.

If you want to generate a random sample with a known CDF $F_X$ from a list of uniformly-distributed samples in $[0,1]$, then just apply $F_X^{-1}$ to each of the samples.

The resulting sample will be distributed like $X$.

In your case, if your uniformly-distributed samples are $x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots$ then the transformed values $\Phi^{-1}(x_1), \Phi^{-1}(x_2), \Phi^{-1}(x_3)\ldots$ will be normally distributed.

Comment: I do not know the PDF unfortunately. But it just occurred to me that applying a coefficient toi my standard deviation before calculating the z-score is an effective way to change the shapes of the resulting distribution (stdev*2 makes for data to be closer to the mean). Maybe that's all I needed

Comment: You don’t need to know it. You just need your list of numbers in $[0,1]$ (your uniform samples), and apply $\Phi^{-1}$ to each of them. Here $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF. The resulting list of samples will be normally distributed.

Comment: Actually no, by doing this I get no value in half of the histogram bins, the scaling is not proportional

Comment: Then your samples are not uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, or your sample size is very small. This is not something I made up, it is a fact and a standard way to transform a uniform random number generator into a generator for any continuous distribution.